# SQL запрос чтобы удалить только последний слеш в записи

Tags: sql

В одном из столбцов в таблице базы данных мне нужно удалить последний символ строки, если это слеш '/'. То есть если последний символ СЛЕШ - удаляем его, если НЕ СЛЕШ - пропускаем.

В данном столбце вот такие записи:

```
/detskie-igrushki/
/podarki/dlya-nego/
/golovolomki/
/kak-oformit-zakaz.html
/uk/podarki/dlya-shefa/
```

и т.д.

То есть символ СЛЕШ, может несколько раз встречаться в одной записи, а удалить нужно ТОЛЬКО слеш в КОНЦЕ, если он есть.

Запрос НАЙТИ и ЗАМЕНИТЬ, вот такой - UPDATE `cs_seo_redirects` SET `dest` = REPLACE( `dest`, '/', '');

удалит все слеши, а не только последний. А нужно удалить слеш только в конце. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность с помощью SQL запроса удалить слеш только в конце?

Comment: `UPDATE cs_seo_redirects SET dest = LEFT(dest, CHAR_LENGTH(dest) - 1) WHERE RIGHT(dest, 1) = '/'`

Comment: Мы также не знаем, какая СУБД и ее версия используется.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант для MySQL.
Необходимы строки находятся по регулярному выражению.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET col_name = SUBSTRING(col_name, 1, LENGTH(col_name) - 1)
WHERE col_name REGEXP '.*\/$'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Chip Deep, благодарю. То что нужно.

Comment: Мы также не знаем, какая  СУБД и ее версия используется.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Спасибо, исправлю

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Спасибо, исправил